# multiline string literals and tests

Tags: javascript

```
var multiply = function (a, b) {
  //An internal comment
  return a * b;
};
var stupid = "function (a, b) {
  return a * b;
  }"
expect(multiply.toString()).toBe(stupid);
```

The test passes, but firefox gives me this:

```
unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error] var stupid = "function (a, b) {
```

Changing the code to use the `\` line terminator stops the test from passing.

```
Expected 'function (a, b) { 
    return a * b; 
}' to be 'function (a, b) {return a * b;}'.
```

The test fails if you escape the multiline string literal.

With newlines, the test still does not pass:

```
var stupid = "function (a, b) {\n
    return a * b;\n
}"
expect(multiply.toString()).toBe(stupid);
```

Comment: `\​` is not a line terminator; it's an escape character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is not passing; it's giving that syntax error.
Javascript does not support (unescaped) multi-line string literals.

With the `\` escapes, it's not passing because your string has no newlines.

The Javsacript source

```
"1\
2"
```

Is evaluated to `"12"`.  Escaped newlines are ignored; they don't become newlines.
You need to add `\n` characters.

Comment: As i said, adding the escape character stops the test from passing.

Comment: Adding the newline characters so that it matches exactly still stops the test from passing. I have also tried it with `\r\n`.

Comment: @Chris: Look carefully at the output.  You're probably missing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Without the backslashes, it's a syntax error. More about string literals [in this HTML transcription](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4) of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

With them, remember that all leading space on subsequent lines is included in the string.

Separately: Your `expect` call will not be reliable. First off, `Function#toString` has never been standardized anywhere (certainly not by the ECMAScript standard). Secondly, it works differently on different engines (some will include comments, others won't; some will reformat the code [so for instance, there may not be a space after `function`], others won't; etc.).

Comment: Not my test. It's part of Javascript Koans. Will open an issue on their github, then. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for including the spec reference. I should have just scrolled down a little further before looking it up. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
var stupid = "function (a, b) {" +
  + "return a * b;" +
  + "}";
```

because javascript does not support multiline string literals, as SLaks pointed out

Comment: this stops the test from passing

Answer (score 0):

There is a more modern answer for this. You can use string literals to handle newlines

```
`1
2`
```